# Tags in filter overlap the ANY button

Tags: bug, design, new-nav

When you have many tags in a single filter, it overlaps the ANY button, at least in Chrome 46.0.2490.

[image: Button overlapping image]

Comment: Does the -1 mean you don't think it overlaps the button?  Or you don't like my red freehand circle?

Comment: Yep, looks ugly. I've fixed it locally by overlaying a gradient fill: https://puu.sh/l2p5O/88e2a1fb42.png